# Can I hide Ubuntu terminal prompts during shutdown?

Tags: ubuntu, shutdown

I'm running ubuntu 13.04 on my Thinkpad T430. Whenever I shutdown, a terminal message which seems (at least, in part) to be related to Virtualbox, but I'm not sure:

[image]

**Is there a way to hide these messages during shutdown?** They do not appear during boot.

### *What I've tried:*

I edited my /etc/init/rc.conf file and commented out `console output` like this:

```
# rc - System V runlevel compatibility
#
# This task runs the old System V-style rc script when changing between
# runlevels.

description "System V runlevel compatibility"
author      "Scott James Remnant <scott@netsplit.com>"

emits deconfiguring-networking
emits unmounted-remote-filesystems

start on runlevel [0123456]
stop on runlevel [!$RUNLEVEL]

export RUNLEVEL
export PREVLEVEL

#console output
env INIT_VERBOSE

task

exec /etc/init.d/rc $RUNLEVEL
```

This resulted in a shorter but still present terminal message:

[image]

I also tried running a shutdown from terminal simply running `sudo init 0` but the `acpid: exiting` message persists.

Comment: Oh no! Now everyone knows my real name! :)

Comment: What happens if you comment out `env INIT_VERBOSE`?

Comment: @terdon No difference, same message (the shorter one in the post).

Comment: Maybe try `mesg n` from [this question](http://superuser.com/questions/153649/how-to-disable-broadcast-messages-on-my-linux-session)

Comment: @beroe No change there either, unless I'm doing it wrong. I just run `mesg n` in terminal and that's it?

Comment: Yes, I would expect that after you type `mesg n` the next shutdown from that terminal would not show the broadcast message, but I didn't test it.

Comment: @beroe Yes, then I did it correctly. The message still displayed, though.

Comment: Another suggestion I saw is using `sudo init 0` to start the halt...

Comment: @beroe I prefer using the shutdown prompt, but if a terminal command it the only way to accomplish it, then I guess that will have to do. I'm new to linux and I'm starting to see a pattern when it comes to simple tasks not having a GUI...

Answer (score 0):

One option is to use `sudo init 0` in initiate the shutdown.

Your next project could be to figure out how to assign this command to a button or menu item...!

Comment: When I try `sudo init 0`, I still get the terminal message `acpid: exiting`.

Comment: Does it show up if you do `sudo init 0 2> /dev/null`? (Perhaps not advised since any other messages won't be shown.) Whatever command you end up finding could probably be packaged into a menu item and certainly aliased to a short command.

Comment: Yes, still shows up then, too.

Comment: Sorry, then. I've reached the end of the rope!