# Kill process but no access to console

Tags: console

After uninstalling Citadel groupware from my headless Debian system located on a remote VPS, obviously something went wrong during removal:

Everytime I try to connect by ssh to that system, the console is littered by continuous broadcast messages, issued by a Citadel process, that had not been uninstalled properly.

Now it is not possible to stop the messages by simply pressing CTRL+C or CTRL+Z.
So the messages keep coming... and I have no access to the console, so it is not possible to issue any command.

Rebooting did not solve the problem.

Does anyone of you have a suggestion to regain access to the console?

Comment: Are you sure it's not possible to issue any command? You may just not see it. I have no experience with Citadel, VPS etc., but maybe you *do* have access, like in [this question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/177050/108618); or [this one](https://superuser.com/q/153649/432690). Assuming you do, if `mesg n` doesn't help then blindly type `sudo ps -e > foo.txt`, then password; download `foo.txt` via `scp`, investigate and decide what to kill.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the answer from Kamil (thanks!) I finally managed to kill the proces that was littering the console.

After logging in via ssh, I blindly typed:

1. `su` {my_su_password}
2. `pkill` {processname}

I tried this method several times, and after attempt 30 or so it worked!